# Why is my derived class constructor deleted?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, default

In the following my compiler says that my derived class constructor cannot be found:

```
    struct Drink
    {
        Drink(const Drink& other);
    };

    struct PepsiMax : Drink {};

    int main()
    {
        PepsiMax myPepsi;         // <--- the default constructor of PepsiMax cannot be referenced, it is a deleted function
    }
```

I know the default constructor of Drink needs to be defined, because I created a copy constructor and the compiler won't make a default constructor for me. However the error message says that it can't find the default constructor for my PepsiMax class, which I expected it to generate. If I define the default constructor for PepsiMax, it then shows an error saying that it can't find the Drink default constructor, which is what I expect.

Can I assume that it's referring to the default constructor of 'Drink' and not 'PepsiMax', or am I misunderstanding something? I expected the compiler to create a default constructor for 'PepsiMax' which calls the base class constructor immediately as the first thing it does.

Edit: My confusion is cleared up, thanks for your help. My explanation about my naive interpretation of the compiler-generated constructor is in an answer.

Comment: It is because Drink doesn't have a default constructor, only the copy constructor Drink::Drink(const Drink &) you just specifed. If you want a default constructor, add Drink() in the structure Drink or PepsiMax() in the structure PepsiMax.

Answer (score 2):

The fix is to write

```
struct Drink
{
    Drink() = default;
    Drink(const Drink& other);
};
```

The presence of the copy constructor obviates the automatic generation of the default constructor (as you know). But this **also means that the compiler cannot generate the default constructor for `PepsiMax`** on which `PepsiMax myPepsi;` is relying. You need to re-introduce it.

Comment: *"The presence of the copy constructor deletes the default constructor. "*  That seems to be a misleading statement, because `deletes the default constructor` can be argued to have specific meaning since C++11.

Comment: @Nawaz: Indeed you're correct. I've played around with the terminology.

Comment: @Bathsheba The copy constructor of Drink means the compiler won't auto-generate the default constructor for DRINK, right? But seeing as though I didn't define any constructors for PepsiMax, it should auto-generate the default constructor for PepsiMax, I would have thought. The error says it can't find the PepsiMax constructor.

Comment: But it *can't* auto-generate that default constructor, since the `Drink` default constructor is missing. That's what I'm trying to say in my answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba Why does the automatic generation of the default PepsiMax constructor rely on the Drink default constructor? I thought that when I create a PepsiMax object first the PepsiMax constructor is called, and then it calls the base class constructor. Sorry, I'm not understanding.

Comment: No, the constructor to the base class object is always called before the child object.

Comment: @Bathsheba Right, but isn't it the case that the child's constructor will call the parent constructor? As the first thing it does. So the child's default constructor would look like Child::Child() { Parent();)  ?

Comment: No it doesn't look like that. `Parent();` cannot be put in the function body. Might I suggest you read a C++ book on these basics?

Comment: @Bathsheba Sorry, then it's in the initialiser list that the parent constructor is called? You're right, I need to do some reading. Thanks.

Comment: You can *think* of it in terms of it being the first item in the initialiser list in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to create a variable of `PepsiMax` type, the default constructor of that class should be called. Since it has a base class (`Drink`), that default constructor will call `Drink`'s default constructor as well. Now in your `Drink` class you have declared your own copy constructor. That prevents the compiler from automatically generating a default constructor, thus it can not be called, thus a default constructor for `PepsiMax` can not be generated as well.

To prevent that, you should explicitly tell the compiler to generate a default constructor with

```
Drink() = default;
```

or implement your own default constructor for `Drink`.

Comment: But defining a copy constructor for Drink stops the compiler auto-generating a default constructor for Drink. I didn't define any constructors for PepsiMax, so I expect the default constructor for it to be generated. However the error message is that it can't find the default constructor for PepsiMax, not for Drink.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice, the default constructor for PepsiMax can not be generated - it would be ill-formed, because it needs to call to the default constructor of Drink, which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

[Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) quotes
that

> The implicitly-declared or defaulted default constructor for class `T` is **undefined** if:
>   `T` has a direct or virtual base which has a deleted default constructor, or it is ambiguous or inaccessible from this constructor.

In your example, implicit default constructor of class `Drink` is *deleted* because of the presence of the copy constructor.

Subsequently, the implicitly-declared or defaulted default constructor for class `PepsiMax` is **undefined** considering its direct base class `Drink` has a deleted default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to the answers others have made. I understand now, and just want to explain my confusion.

```
struct Base
{
    Base(const Base& other);       // <---- My copy constructor, putting this here prevents the compiler generating a default and empty constructor
};

Derived : Base
{
    // Nothing here. The compiler should generate a default constructor here
    // Something like Derived() : Base::Base() {}
}
```

Now, there are two ways to think about how the compiler goes about this for a naive person (me). The way I was thinking is that the compiler does the equivalent of pasting the default constructor in place, and then compiling. If this is what it actually did, then error message should be the same as if I pasted that line in manually, which is actually a different error, that it can't find the Base default constructor, not the Derived default constructor.

However, what 'obviously' happens is that the compiler tries to generates the:

```
Derived() : Base::Base(){}
```

Parses it, fails to find Base::Base(), and doesn't generate that line at all, and then complains that it can't find the Derived default constructor. This was obvious for those who answered. The confusion here was about 'how' the compiler exactly generates the default constructor. Thanks for enlightening me just that little bit extra.